# How to use aggregate functions in Solr DiH?

Tags: solr, dih

I have a requirement where the aggregation of the column values has to go into a Solr document field.

Oracle supports **listagg** and similar functions.

When used in DiH it throws an error , something like

> sub grouping not allowed

The oracle sql query is

```
select subjectId, listagg(rank  || '---' || replace( trim(studentLastname) ,',',' '), '; ') within group (order by rank)   As rankersList where subjectId > 0 Group by subjectId;
```

The above query gives students and their ranks for a given subject each on one row.

What will be smartest way in DIH with optimal performance.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks @javacreed.Thats a good idea but  its a legacy DB and nothing can be done on db side.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution will be to create a View in oracle DB for the same using the complex query and then in the solr DIH use that view.